# How to... Node js with Google/Facebook OAuth signin and Google Checkout

Tags: node.js, single-sign-on, google-checkout

Hi I am totally new to Nodejs, but would anyone point me in the right direction on how I can quickly get Nodejs running with Google/facebook/openid single sign-on and google checkout integration.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Passport package](http://passportjs.org/) seems to be the best. You can find a lot of useful modules on node wiki page in GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

For Single Sign On, check out Passport-SAML module 
https://github.com/bergie/passport-saml